# Assign specific rows in one list as NAs based on a second list of row numbers

Tags: r

Here is some code to simulate my problem. The simulated data has the same dimensions (74 subjects, 178 time points in a time series, 294 variables + 8 nuisance variables)

```
fulldata = lapply(1:74, function(i) matrix(rnorm(300,0,1), ncol=300,nrow=178))

rownumbers = seq(1:178)

badrows = lapply(1:74, function(i) sample(rownumbers, size=10, rownumbers,replace=FALSE))
```

Now what I need to do is replace the rows listed in each vector in the list badrows in the corresponding matrix in the list "fulldata" with NAs

These are time points that are corrupted and will be interpolated. But first the bad values must be replaced with NAs.

This doesn't work.

```
lapply(1:74, function(l) lapply(1:74, function(l) fulldata[[l]][badrows[[l]],1:294]<-NA))

returns list that looks like this:

  [[74]][[72]]
  [1] NA

  [[74]][[73]]
  [1] NA

  [[74]][[74]]
  [1] NA
```

This doesn't work either.

```
lapply(1:74, function(l) fulldata[[l]][badrows[[l]],1:294]<-NA)

Returns list that looks like this:
  [[72]]
  [1] NA

  [[73]]
  [1] NA

  [[74]]
  [1] NA
```

This just returns a vector of NAs

```
sapply(1:74, function(i) fulldata[[i]][badrows[[i]],1:294] <- NA) 


[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[34] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[67] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I also tried some stuff with mapply but lost the lines when R froze up and don't recall exactly what I did. What I am expecting is for the output to be like this, where the "bad rows" are replaced by NA just for columns 1-294 and 295-300 are returned unchanged :

(Can't get the table to appear right here, but leaving it anyway)

```
  | var1 | var2 | var3 | ........ | var295 | ..... | var300 |
  |------|------|------|----------|--------|-------|--------|
  | 3    | 1    | 5    | .......  | .72    | ..... | .23    |
  | NA   | NA   | NA   | ........ | .10    | ..... | .98    |
  | 5    | 7    | 12   | ........ | .42    | ..... | 1.2    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
lapply(1:74, function(iii) "[<-"(fulldata[[iii]], badrows[[iii]],, NA))
```

which is equivalent to

```
mapply(function(x,y) "[<-"(x, y,, NA), fulldata, badrows, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) # without setting SIMPLIFY to FALSE you get one large matrix
```

and

```
mapply("[<-", fulldata, i=badrows, MoreArgs=alist(j=, value=NA), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# j=  # this corresponds to the empty second argument in [i,j]
```

Your code above suffers from the fact that subset assignment returns the value that is assigned, not the whole object.

```
 sapply(1:74, function(i) fulldata[[i]][badrows[[i]],1:294] <- NA) 
 #  does the same thing as ...
 sapply(1:74, function(i) NA)
```

To improve this, you could make the function to return the whole object:

```
 sapply(1:74, function(i) {fulldata[[i]][badrows[[i]],1:294] <- NA; fulldata[[i]]})
```

Comment: Thank you! I like that you explain where my code went wrong. A lot of times I get an answer that works, but I don't always see exactly where I went wrong. I'm "R-competent" rather than "R-fluent" so to speak, you might say, and always looking to get better.